# Rip an audio CD 1:1

Tags: backup, ripping, audio-cd

Is there a way to rip an audio CD to an ISO9660 file? I've tried simple things like `dd` in the past and it hasn't worked. I'd like to essentially have a mirror image of exactly what's on the disk, not even necessarily a folder of WAV files.

I do understand that I could rip the CD to WAV files or even FLAC files, but is there a way to just duplicate the disc to one file, so I could extract WAVs or FLACs from it later on? The idea is to be able to make a virtually identical copy of the source media.

Comment: What was wrong with `dd`? How about `cat`?

Comment: `dd` gave me errors. I don't have a CD on hand right now to demonstrate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An audio [CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc) doesn't contain a filesystem at all. The [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Book_%28CD_standard%29) is defined as a particular stream of bits directly representing sounds. This is unlike [DVDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD), where a [video DVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video) is a DVD with a [UDF filesystem with a particular structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disc_Format).

The classical CD burning suite, [cdrecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdrtools), includes [`cdda2wav`](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/cdrecord/cdda2wav.1.html) to rip an audio CD to a WAV file, and [`cdrecord -audio`](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/cdrecord/cdrecord.1.html) to burn a WAV file to an audio CD. Another tool for CD ripping is [cdparanoia](http://www.xiph.org/paranoia/); it tries very hard to be as faithful as possible to the audio data. Many CD burning GUIs have a button or menu entry to rip, burn or copy audio CDs.

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure as to how data was stored on an audio CD.

Comment: `cdparanoia` was created as a patch on a `cdda2wav` version from 1997 and cdparanoia is mostly unmaintained since nearly 15 years now. `cdda2wav` added the paranoia code from cdparanoia in 2002. Since then, many code enhancements have been introduced in the libparanoia that us used by cdda2wav. Today, the best choice for `Ripping` seems to be cdda2wav.

Answer (score 5):

If you want an image file of an audio CD, you can use readcd/readom in TOC mode. It will output a .toc and a .bin files that you can use to burn identical copies in other optical media. The .toc file can be converted to .cue format with toc2cue and obtain a .cue file that is compatible with software available for other operating systems (and can be read by applications like cdrecord/wodim, braseo and k3b).

Comment: Any chance of bundling it into a single file, other than tarring or zipping it?

Comment: Just curious, what about copy protection on CDs (if it exists) or DVDs?